# MySQL --lowercase_table_names in php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, windows, case-sensitive

I have a MySQL database on a few windows and Linux servers. On some servers the table names are lowercase but on other servers they are uppercase. 
I have studied that there is a file "my.ini" with a setting --lowercase_table_names that forces php to ignore the case when it accesses MySQL.

My problem is that my servers are on shared webhosting and I'm not allowed to edit the file my.ini.

Is there any way how I could set the --lowercase_table_names in the php code (for example in the mysql_connect() or mysql_query function?

Comment: yes. For example on server one the table names are: Sites, Users, DataValues and on server two the table names are: sites, users, datavalues ... I would like to have one php script that queries the DB and that works both on server 1 and server 2

Comment: There is no way to set this directive from php. You will need to factor your code appropriately or configure it in `my.ini`.